# .click won't click when wrapped in other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.likeBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});

});
```

It works when it just alone but when I put it in the spot I need it to be, inside about three divs it doesn't work anymore, why?

You can see me trying to use it here: http://absdfsderedfdsfrr.tumblr.com/

CSS

```
.like_button {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
}

.like_button iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
ul#meta li.likeBtn {
    display: block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/BPnlzww8v/like.png');
}
ul#meta li.clicked {
    background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/Y36m6h0qu/liked.png')!important;
}
```

HTML (buried in divs though)

```
<ul id="meta">
<li class="likeBtn">{LikeButton color="grey" size="20"}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please share the HTML and CSS of the affected div(s)?

Comment: http://absdfsderedfdsfrr.tumblr.com/

You can see the heart on the left that I'm trying to change

Comment: I think, you might get some help from Tumblr API in this, while editting the theme template!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     $('.likeBtn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That might not be the issue. Being a child doesn't cause any issue in jQuery as even the first div element is a child of `body`.

Have you tried using:

```
$('.likeBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('class', 'clicked');
});
```

Fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/XupXa/1/

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't seem to be working? Maybe there a fault in my code I'll doublt check

Comment: There might be something missing from the theme side, sure! You should give it a second look..

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for this, please follow the link demo below, I have done a example for you to get an idea about and fix your bug

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$( ".likeBtn").click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "clicked" );
});
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="meta">
<li class="likeBtn" >Click to toggle</li>
<li class="likeBtn clicked">clicked</li>
</ul >
```

CSS

```
.likeBtn {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
 background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/BPnlzww8v/like.png');   

  }
  .blue {
    color: red;
  }
.red {
    color: blue;
  }
  .clicked {
     background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/Y36m6h0qu/liked.png')!important;
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2BXr/2/)